# Split string using delimiter that the SSRS passes - select multiple values from the parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2019

I have this stored procedure where I am trying to select multiple values from the parameter `Bkt`. This works okay when I select one value from `Bkt` but `Bkt` has different values that I want to be able to select from in the SSRS.

For example in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbu80.png) you can see that there are `CFI` and `DPR` inside of `Bkt`. I want to be able to select both `CFI` and `DPR` in `Bkt`.

I need to keep the stored procedure so I am trying to split the delimited string that SSRS passes. I can't figure it out. I tried changing the delimiter by using an expression in the Parameters mapping section but I couldn't figure that out either. I am just so lost.

This is my Stored Procedure

```
@Press varchar(10),
@BKT varchar (10)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
select * From (
Select FAC,SPEC_NEW.Tread_Code, Case When cosw.tread_code = spec_new.tread_code Then 'Scheduled' else 'Alternative' end AS Size, COUNT(Distinct loc.serial )  QTY , 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY FAC, SPEC_NEW.Tread_Code
                 ORDER BY fac, Case When cosw.tread_code = spec_new.tread_code Then 'Scheduled' else 'Alternative' end DESC, SPEC_NEW.Tread_Code
           ) AS r_num
FROM [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work] cosw with (nolock)
Inner Join [SharedData].dbo.spec_master Spec with (nolock) On spec.spec=Cosw.SPEC
Inner Join [SharedData].dbo.spec_master SPEC_NEW with (nolock) On SPEC_NEW.ARTICLE=SPEC.article
Inner Join [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Locator] LOC with (Nolock) ON LOC.SPEC=SPEC_NEW.SPEC
Where Cosw.FAC=@press and Loc.BKT = @bkt
GROUP BY FAC, cosw.Tread_Code, SPec_new.Tread_Code, Loc.Bkt
) as a
where r_num=1
order by FAC



END
```

I have another Stored Procedure where I am getting `Press` and `Bkt`

```
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select distinct FAC as Press, Loc.BKT as Bkt
FROM [TireTrack].[dbo].[cos_work], [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[Locator] LOC 
END
```

I was using [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2844/working-with-multiselect-parameters-for-ssrs-reports/) as a reference

Comment: Do you *really* need those `NOLOCK` hints? You do understand what the `NOLOCK` hint does, right? It's *not* a magic "go faster button". Also, that `ROW_NUMBER` expression looks odd; looking at your `GROUP BY` I don't think that it can return anything other than `1`.

Comment: STOP splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using? Please edit the tags as appropriate

Comment: I know what NOLOCK does and there's a reason why I am using it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual example for you how to handle comma separated parameter to a stored procedure.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, vehicleMake VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl (vehicleMake) VALUES
('Chevrolet'),
('Tesla'),
('Audi'),
('Nissan');

DECLARE @ParameterList VARCHAR(max) = '1,2';

-- Method #1
-- XML and XQuery
-- SQL Server 2008 onwards
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT xmldata = TRY_CAST('<root><r>' + 
         REPLACE(@ParameterList, @separator, '</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML)
)
SELECT tbl.* 
FROM rs CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root/r/text()') AS t(c)
    INNER JOIN @tbl AS tbl ON tbl.id = c.value('.','INT');

-- Method #2
-- STRING_SPLIT()
-- SQL Server 2016 onwards
SELECT tbl.*
FROM @tbl AS tbl INNER JOIN 
     STRING_SPLIT(@ParameterList, ',') AS ss
     ON tbl.ID = ss.value;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | vehicleMake |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Chevrolet   |
|  2 | Tesla       |
+----+-------------+
```